# Does the SQL CASE statement treat variables differently from columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have the following code in a stored procedure and am trying to conditionally format a calculated number based on its length (if the number is less than 4 digits, pad with leading zeros). However, my case statement is not working. The "formattedNumber2" result is the one I'm looking for.

I'm assuming the case statement treats the variable strangely, but I also don't know of a way around this.

```
DECLARE @Number int = 5

SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN (LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Number)) > 4) 
          THEN @Number
       ELSE RIGHT('0000' + CAST(@Number AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) 
    END AS formattedNumber,
    LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Number)) AS numberLength,
    RIGHT('0000' + CAST(@Number AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) AS formattedNumber2
```

I get the following results when I run the query:

```
formattedNumber   numberLength  formattedNumber2
-------------------------------------------------
         5             1              0005
```

Comment: You should ALWAYS specify a size with varchar. You are not even consistent here in the same query. Do you know the default size of varchar? Do you know that it can change depending on if it is a column, variable or parameter? https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: Waltersobchakeit

Comment: "You're not wrong, you're just being mean" - come on, man. Let me and my bad grammar be

Comment: Seriously? I offer some advice and that is your response? And no I am not being mean. I was offering that as help so you don't end up with messed up data. But whatever. That isn't bad grammar, it is sloppy coding that can have serious ramifications.

Comment: And since I am sure you think it was me, the downvote was NOT me. I actually think you have a good question, been asked many times before but yours wasn't bad.

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/433d6/202)**

The problem is you are using different data type on your case , integer and string. So the `CASE` stay with the first type he find and convert the rest.

```
 CASE WHEN (LEN(convert(VARCHAR, @Number)) > 4) THEN convert(VARCHAR, @Number)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done a lot easier with `format()` since version 2012.

```
format(n,
       '0000')
```

And that would also handle negative values, which your current approach apparently doesn't.

Prior 2012 it can be handled with basically `replicate()` and `+` (string concatenation).

```
isnull(replicate('-',
                 -sign(n)), '')
+
isnull(replicate('0',
                 4
                 -
                 len(cast(abs(n) AS varchar(10)))
                 ),
       '')
+
cast(abs(n) AS varchar(10))
```

(It targets `integer` values, choose a larger length for the `varchar` casts for `bigint`.)

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=122183aba2844f6ae2c42f0229c124f4)